# Body created using Libgdx Box2d is not being showing on screen when project is run

Tags: libgdx, box2d, render

**project:** I've been working on a little project using libgdx-box2d in which i want to create an object, render it to the screen and apply gravity to it so that it collides with the ground. The part i am currently working on is creating and rendering the body.

**Problem:** The problem is that the body that i created is not showing on the screen when i run the project, i feel that i have created the body correctly as there are no compilation problems.

**What i tried:**

1. I tried many things such as increasing the radius of  my circle to
   make it bigger (more visible)
2. zooming in to the screen by doing `camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() /10, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() /10);`
    incase it was
   too small to see but no matter what i tried the object i created
   cant be seen.
3. Changing the position of the body to different x,y locations

**Outcome i want:** What i would like is to possibly get an answer as to why the body i created isn't being shown and some help in rendering it so that it can be seen. I hope the structure i laid out my question is clear and informational. Thank you guys in advance for any help

**here is my relevant code:**

```
package com.mohamed.JungleFighter;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.writer.document.soap.Body;

//i'm extending libgdx's built in game class which implements the activity listener
public class JungleFighterMain extends Game {

private OrthographicCamera camera;
private SpriteBatch sBatch;
private Texture player;
private Texture enemy;
//private SpriteBatch enemyBatch;
private Sprite sprite1;
private Sprite sprite2;
//just setting my game heighty and width
public static int gameWidth = 1280, gameHeight = 720;
private World world;
private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
p 

@Override
public void create () {
    //camera related
camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() /10, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() /10);
                //end of camera related

//BOX2D CODE FOR CREATING WWORLD
    World world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true); 

    //creating box2d body definition
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    //setting body type to dynamic
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    //position
    bodyDef.position.set(0, 0);
    //sending what i just made to the world i created
    // making a circle with a radius of 6

    CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
    circle.setRadius(30f);

    //making my fixtures for the circle
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = circle;
    fixtureDef.density = 0.5f; 
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
    //making it bounce a little
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.6f;

    //addding fixture attributes to my ball
    //Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

    //end of creating my circle ball 

    //creating my actual ball in the world

    world.createBody(bodyDef).createFixture(fixtureDef);

    circle.dispose();
    //GROUND START

    BodyDef bodyGround = new BodyDef();
    bodyGround.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
    bodyGround.position.set(-100,-100);

    //setting shape of ground

    ChainShape groundShape = new ChainShape();
    groundShape.createChain(new Vector2[] {new Vector2(-250, 0), new Vector2(250, 0)});

    //fixtures for ground
    FixtureDef fixtureDefGround = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDefGround.shape = groundShape;
    fixtureDefGround.friction = 0.5f;
    fixtureDefGround.restitution = 0;

    world.createBody(bodyGround).createFixture(fixtureDefGround);
    groundShape.dispose();
}

public  void dispose() {
    world.dispose();
}

public void render (float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // camera related
       sBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); 

    debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);

    world.step(TIMESTEP, VELOCITYITERATIONS, POSITIONITERATIONS);   
    }
}
    public  void resize(int width, int height){
    }

    public  void pause(){
    }

    public  void resume(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because   //debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);, you don't draw your world?

Comment: No from what i believe the debug.Renderer is only for testing purposes, its not actually needed for rendering, its optional (usually used for debug testing cases to gather data)

Comment: What you want to see? You are not drawing nothing..

Comment: Thats an interesting point, i tried uncommenting debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined); but that just causes my project to instantly crash upon launch, it compiles but as soon as i run it, it crashes

Comment: I have updated my code a little, uncommenting debug.Renderer and fixing the crash issue but my project still will not render my body. @Paul

Comment: Maybe your ball is falling too fast, try to add a ground, and also, keep in mind that your ball is 30 meters wide

Comment: OK i've now added some ground too (see updated code) at no surprise that isnt rendering either. It seems that any "body" i create cannot render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after several hours of research i finally realized i needed to add camera.viewportHeight = ; camera.viewportWidth ; camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight); –

Answer (score 0):

In Java its not enough to declare an object, as you have with:

```
private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer
```

You also need to instantiate it, otherwise it is a null reference. Try adding

```
debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer()
```

To your create function to avoid the error you mention in the comments. The constructor may also take some arguments but I am not familiar with Box2D or LibGDX.

Comment: i tried adding this under create()                            debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer(world, camera.combined); but i get an error stating to remove my arguments from the parameters of Box2DDebugRenderer. But when i do remove them i go back to where i started (nothing being rendered)

Comment: From the documentation the constructor takes a World, and a Matrix4 object that is the projection matrix. Hence you'll want to pass camera.projection instead. Without the code and exact error I can't really troubleshoot further than that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried changing it to                    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer(world, camera.projection); but i get this error
"The constructor Box2DDebugRenderer(World, Matrix4) is undefined". i also change my debug renderer to   debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer(world, camera.projection); under the render() stage

Comment: No problem. Ok, I apologise as I seem to have misinformed you there, the documentation I viewed may be incorrect/outdated. In your create function you need `debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer()` and in the render function you just need `debugRenderer.render(world, camera.projection)`, you may need to change the variable names. This appears to inform the renderer the world information to render, and the camera to render from. Hope this helps.

Comment: ok after several hours of research i finally realized i needed to add            camera.viewportHeight = ;  
           camera.viewportWidth ; camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight);